# Datalink-layer and Physical-layer devices in smart phone

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, router

Since we are using our smart phones to connect to Internet, it should follow any one of the network models. If it follows TCP/IP five layer model, and If I'm using public wi-fi then wi-fi routers belongs to network-layer(I think), then which device in our smart phones belongs to data-link layer and physical-layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smartphones have network interfaces just like every other computer with a network connection. Typically, phones have both a Wi-Fi network interface and a cellular network interface (e.g. a 4G modem).

For example, [this overview](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-845-mobile-platform) of the Snapdragon 845 (a popular system on chip for modern Android phones) mentions that the chip has an LTE modem (4G) as well ad 802.11ad and 802.11ac Wifi modems.

These physical devices and their corresponding firmware and drivers are typically the components responsible for implementing the lower layers of communication, including the data link and physical layers. Most of the network layer and the layers above are typically done in the operating system.